# Pie chart 3d json series

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, pie-chart

Please help in creating 3D pie chart . I've a problem with loading the Json series.
My code:
[`jsfiddle.net/e39taLt5/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/e39taLt5/1/)

json file:

```
([["poludniowy","1040"],["poludniowo-zachodni","710"],["poludniowo-wschodni","692"],["zachodni","638"],["polnocno-zachodni","448"],["wschodni","80"],["","14"],["polnocno-wschodni","9"]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON isn't JSON :) It contains extra brackets `(` and `)`. I guess it's a try of creating JSONP, which may be unnecessary.

Then, we don't know what your `fixFormat()` function does, there may be bug.

The next thing is about values - these are strings, while should be numbers: `'1040'` -> `1040`. Solution is simple like this:

```
    data.map(function(e) {
       e[1] = parseInt(e[1], 10); 
    });
```

Another thing is that you don't have `options` object and trying to create two series (any reason for that?).

After fixing all this stuff, you will get rendered chart:  http://jsfiddle.net/e39taLt5/2/

**Note:** 
I'm using static data instead of JSON, just for demo purposes.

Comment: I reworked the json file in this way.
`[{"polnocno-wschodni":"9"},{"wschodni":"80"},{"polnocno-zachodni":"448"},{"zachodni":"638"},{"poludniowo-wschodni":"701"},{"poludniowo-zachodni":"710"},{"poludniowy":"1055"}]`
Also does not work:
`http://jsfiddle.net/e39taLt5/6/`

Comment: It won't work in jsFiddle because of CORS. I'm not sure why have you changed JSON format..? I just asked for replacing strings with numbers and removing extra brackets..

Comment: These things are tested by: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Json reworked to fit the specifications higcharts . But I do not want to work

Comment: If you refer Ed's answer, then format suggested there is completely wrong for Highcharts. What you had before was perfectly fine, except these two things I referred to: strings instead of numbers (!) and extra brackets.

Comment: Okay, I reworked the json file , such as was before, but it does not work ( method `$.getJSON` )
http://jsfiddle.net/e39taLt5/10/

Comment: Could you try to work on my example? You have other errors in code. Like missing options variable..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your JSON data is invalid.
Use this site to check the syntax:  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You have:

```
([
    ["poludniowy","1040"],
    ["poludniowo-zachodni","710"],
    ["poludniowo-wschodni","692"],
    ["zachodni","638"],
    ["polnocno-zachodni","448"],
    ["wschodni","80"],
    ["","14"],
    ["polnocno-wschodni","9"]
])
```

But it should look something like this:

```
{
    "poludniowy":"1040",
    "poludniowo-zachodni":"710",
    "poludniowo-wschodni":"692",
    "zachodni":"638",
    "polnocno-zachodni":"448",
    "wschodni":"80",
    "":"14",
    "polnocno-wschodni":"9"
}
```